# Quantifying the loss of efficiency incurred by a pseudo-likelihood estimator relative to the true maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: maximum-likelihood, efficiency

I'm working on a couple of problems where I use pseudo-likelihood (a.k.a. composite likelihood) as an estimation method since full maximum likelihood is not feasible.

To give some background without getting into very specific details, in both projects the data are iid samples of clustered binary data such that there are dependencies within each cluster. That is, I have iid observations of $Y_{1}, ..., Y_{n}$ such that $Y_{k} = \{ Y_{k1}, ..., Y_{km_{k}} \}$ where $m_{k}$ can be rather large (say, 100).

Since there is no simple a prior choice for the distribution of multivariate binary data, I attack the problem by modeling the bivariate distributions and producing a pseudo-likelihood by summing over the pairwise likelihoods. This is sensible because the likelihood of a bivariate binary vector is a simple function of the cell probabilities and can be conveniently re-parameterized by the marginal probabilities and the odds ratio, giving interpretable parameters in terms of the mean and dependence structure. Specifically, I maximize

$$ {\rm CL}(\Theta) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} w_{k} \sum_{(i,j)}\log \Big( P(Y_{ki}, Y_{kj} | \Theta) \Big ) $$

as a function of the parameter $\Theta$. The index $(i,j)$ is meant to represent all pairs of observations within cluster $k$. The weights $w_{k} = m_{k}/\binom{m_{k}}{2}$ are incorporated so that a particular cluster doesn't have an artificially large influence due to the pairwise expansion.

It's a fact that pseudo-likelihood estimators are, at best, as efficient as full maximum likelihood estimates, and are usually less efficient (clearly). In other work I've read whenever pseudo-likelihood methods are used there is some discussion/results attempting to quantify the loss of efficiency. This leads me to my question:

Since I can't feasibly calculate the maximum likelihood estimate in terms of my model parameters (except in simple cases that are actually sub-models captured exactly by the composite likelihood estimator, such as independence), how exactly can I quantify this loss of efficiency? Would it be at all convincing to anyone if I were to present estimation results when the true model is and is not a subset of the space covered by the composite likelihood estimator (since it is simple enough to simulate data with higher order dependencies than those captured by the pairwise likelihoods) and show that not too much precision is lost?

My initial thought was to calculate the asymptotic relative efficiency of the maximizer of ${\rm CL}(\Theta)$. I have an analytic expression for the asymptotic covariance matrix of the pseudo-likelihood estimator which I can numerically compute if I must (but that will require me to calculate the hessian, ugh). But, I can't make much headway with the analogous quantity for the MLE, so that's dead in the water, unless I'm missing something.